# ASP NET EventHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listening class and inside it is my event handler.
The event is subscribed to page.aspx.cs and when the event is raised I want to change the text of lblStatus.
If I use the button event the text is changed without problem, the issue persists just if I use my event.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Initial Status"></asp:Label>
```

When the event happens I want to change the text from **Initial Status** to **New Status**

C# code

```
    HttpListenerHelper httpListenerHelper;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        httpListenerHelper = new HttpListenerHelper();

        httpListenerHelper.EventStartTransactionReceived += Event_EventStartTransactionReceived;

        httpListenerHelper.StartListen();
    }

    private void Event_EventStartTransactionReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "New Status";
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

Comment: HttpListenerHelper seams to be a custom class and we don't know what it does.

Comment: Yes, HttpListenerHelper is a custom class and when the listener receives a request containing StartTransaction, I invoke the event.
                if (url == "/StartTransaction")
                {
    EventStartTransactionReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
                }